# Multiprocess UDP server program in Python behaves differently on Linux and MacOS

Tags: python, macos, networking, multiprocessing, udp

I have a multiprocess UDP server in Python (see below code). It correctly spawns required amount of processes. On Linux, it load balances the UDP data between different processes properly but on MacOS, only one of the process seems to receive the data. Am I missing some parameters on MacOS here?

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import socket
import os

def s(PORT):
    UDP_IP = ""
    UDP_PORT = PORT

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                        socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    print(f"Started server {os.getpid()}")

    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print(f"Received message on {os.getpid()}: {data}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"Program started {os.getpid()}")
    with Pool(5) as p:
        p.map(s, [8000] * 5)
```

```
(Output MacOS)

Program started 32205
Started server 32233
Started server 32235
Started server 32234
Started server 32232
Started server 32236
Received message on 32233: b'hello 1'
Received message on 32233: b'hello 2'
Received message on 32233: b'hello 3'
Received message on 32233: b'hello 4'
Received message on 32233: b'hello 5'
Received message on 32233: b'hello 6'
Received message on 32233: b'hello 7'
Received message on 32233: b'hello 8'
Received message on 32233: b'hello 9'
Received message on 32233: b'hello 10'
```

```
(Output Linux)

Program started 1860163
Started server 1860165
Started server 1860164
Started server 1860166
Started server 1860167
Started server 1860168
Received message on 1860167: b'hello 1'
Received message on 1860165: b'hello 2'
Received message on 1860167: b'hello 3'
Received message on 1860167: b'hello 4'
Received message on 1860164: b'hello 5'
Received message on 1860168: b'hello 6'
Received message on 1860164: b'hello 7'
Received message on 1860167: b'hello 8'
Received message on 1860167: b'hello 9'
Received message on 1860164: b'hello 10'
```

I have tried SO_REUSEADDR as well but it only starts one process. I guess other processes are waiting for bind to complete but first process has already got a hold of it.

I also tried daemonizing with gunicorn but the same problem of only one worker receiving data exists there.

Here is a simpler version of the program with gunicorn.

```py
# run with 'gunicorn udp_server --reuse-port -w 5'
import socket
import os

UDP_IP = ""
UDP_PORT = 8001

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEPORT, 1)
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
print(f"Process started {os.getpid()}")

while True:
    data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
    print(f"Received message ({os.getpid()}): {data}")
```

Extra: to send udp data

```bash
for i in `seq 100`; do echo -n "hello $i" | nc -u -w 1 127.0.0.1 8000; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't create 5 different sockets. Create one socket in the parent process, it will be inherited by the children.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import socket
import os

def s(sock):
    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print(f"Received message on {os.getpid()}: {data}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(f"Program started {os.getpid()}")
    UDP_IP = ""
    UDP_PORT = 8000

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                        socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    print(f"Started server {os.getpid()}")
    with Pool(5) as p:
        p.map(s, [sock] * 5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This worked as expected under both OSes and surprisingly without setting the SO_REUSEPORT option.

Comment: I did notice one issue when I was testing it on my Mac -- I can't interrupt the server. I have to kill it with `kill -9`.

Comment: I noticed that too. I am integrating `signal` module to mitigate this.

Comment: Also, if we do not use Pool but create individual processes with the Process function, then the program is interruptible.

Comment: See my final solution - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77073984/13109255

Comment: If your solution is more complete, feel free to unaccept mine and accept your own.

Comment: I think it's ok. Your answer was a great start point.

Answer (score 0):

Async + multiprocess version

```py
import asyncio
import os
import socket
import multiprocessing as mp

class EchoServerProtocol:
    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        print(f"Received message on {os.getpid()}: {data}")

    def connection_lost(self, a):
        pass


async def s(sock):
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    transport, protocol = await loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
        lambda: EchoServerProtocol(), sock=sock
    )
    print(f"Started server {os.getpid()}")

    # Wait forever
    await asyncio.Event().wait()


def main(sock):
    asyncio.run(s(sock))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"Program started {os.getpid()}")
    UDP_IP = ""
    UDP_PORT = 8000

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    
    for _ in range(5):
        mp.Process(target=main, args=(sock,)).start()
    
    while True:
        if len(mp.active_children()) < 5:
            print("Starting new process")
            mp.Process(target=main, args=(sock,)).start()
```

MacOS interruptible with CTRL+C version

```py
import socket
import os
import multiprocessing as mp


def s(sock):
    print(f"Started server {os.getpid()}")
    while True:
        data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024)
        print(f"Received message on {os.getpid()}: {data}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"Program started {os.getpid()}")
    UDP_IP = ""
    UDP_PORT = 8000
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

    for _ in range(5):
        mp.Process(target=s, args=(sock,)).start()
    
    while True:
        if len(mp.active_children()) < 5:
            print("Starting new process")
            mp.Process(target=s, args=(sock,)).start()
```